# Google Chrome fixed positioning issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a site that uses the Bootstrap framework, with a video background that uses fixed positioning and %100 height and width. I am also trying to create a sticky nav using fixed positioning. The code below works great in Firefox and even IE9 & 10, but not Chrome? I am completely at a loss as to what to do here, and I would prefer to avoid using JS to fix the issue. My code is as follows (note: this site is being developed as a Shopify theme for funzies, so don't mind the liquid code)
The HTML markup:

```
    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0"> 
  <source src="{{'jelly_fish_particle_system_640x360.mp4'| asset_url}}" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>

  <a class="brand" href="index.liquid">{{'logo.png' | asset_url | img_tag}}</a>
<div class="navbar">

  <div class="navbar-inner">

    <ul class="nav pull-right">

      <li><a href="#">Link</a>          
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>          
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>          
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

   </ul>
```

and the relevant CSS:

```
#video_background
{
  position: fixed; 
  right: 0px; 
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 
  z-index: -1000; 
  overflow: hidden
}
.brand
{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:11;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.navbar
{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:10;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;

}
```

The issue is that in Chrome, the nav bar is not sticky, by which I mean when you scroll, so does the navbar. In FireFox and IE9 and 10, it stays put, as does the video in the background. I have searched for different answers, and have found no solutions that have worked for my particular issue. I have tried adding heights to the HTML and Body tags. When I remove the `z-index` from the video, and add `position:relative; z-index:5` to `.container` it seems to work just fine, but I feel like it would be cleaner, and easier to maintain and keep track of indexes, to just have the negative index on the video, not a positive index on any potential elements that are going to be on top of it. Any thoughts on this matter? Is there anyway to keep the original format (i.e. `#video_background{z-index:-1000;}`) and have it work out?

Comment: could be that their all fixed

Comment: @brandonjordon I was wondering about that too, but the W3Schools defines position fixed as "The element is positioned relative to the browser window." So I don't know how they would be interfering with one another, since they aren't relative to each other, but to the window itself.

Comment: I know you don't want to but you may have to use JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: @brandonjordan I think I will just end up going with the z-index on the content rather than the video. I wish I knew why Chrome was rendering it so differently from Firefox and IE though

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact issue in Chrome. It appears that for some reason Chrome does not like negative z-index values. Once I removed the negative z-index from the video element it worked just fine.